# Find period with lowest variability in time series r

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I have a time series and would like to find the period that has the lowest contiguous variability, i.e. the period in which the rolling SD hovers around the minimum for the longest consecutive time steps.

```
test=c(10,12,14,16,13,13,14,15,15,14,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,15,14,15,12,11,10)
rol=rollapply(x, width=4, FUN=sd)
rol
```

I can easily see from the data or the graph that the longest period with the lowest variability start at t=11. Is there a function that can help me find this period of continued low variability, perhaps trying automatically different size for the rolling window? I am not interested in finding the time step with the lowest SD, but a period where this low SD is more consistent than others.

All I can think for now is looking at the difference between rol[i]-rol[i+1], looping through the vector and use a counter to find periods of consecutive low values of SD. I was also thinking of using cluster analysis, something like  `kmeans(rol, 5)` but I can have long time series which are complex and I would have to manually pick the number of clusters.

Comment: If we can assume that the minimum is 0 as in the example then `with(rle(test), max(lengths))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck ok I think I see what you are suggesting, however I shouldn't mention that I don't have zero.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I have played with this solution, I still have to use the rolling sd but then I can use rle. How can I retrieve the index in the time series of where the repetiton begins based on the result from rle?

Comment: Sum the lengths prior to the maximum length and add 1.  That is, it begins at `with(rle(test), sum(lengths[1:(which.max(lengths)-1)])+1)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck your suggestion really helped. However it is not a procedure that can be completely automated if you want a more qualitative evaluation, so I used a combination of lenghts and value.